# Fortigateでポリシーを設定する際にGUIでサービスという場所で各プロトコルに対してacceptかdenyと設定しますが、設定に使用するアクションにリセットは項目増やせますか？

Tags: network

FortiGateでポリシーなどのセキュリティ的な設定をする際に、GUI画面でサービスやアプリケーションコントロール？などを、どのあたりで設定するかはわからないのですが「ftpプロトコル」の通信で異常を検知した際に通信をブロックするのではなく通信をリセットを（自動的に）行なってくれるような設定をしたいです。

ただ、調べていく中で恐らくAcceptとDeny以外にリセットというアクションを作成できるようなのですが、こちらはどのように作成できるのでしょうか？
また、「denyやaccept以外にリセットアクションを作成するということではないぞ？」な場合はそちらの点もご教授いただきたいです。

FortiGate 50EでOSが５〜あたり何で古い機種なので、分かる方は古くてその機種ではできないなどあればその点も教えていただきたいです。

知識が浅く理解が難しいので詰まっております。宜しくお願いいたします。